# Averaging across columns based on their names in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to take the average of each set of ***similarly named columns*** whose names end in `...1S` and `...2S`  (ex: `ex1S`,`ex2S`) at `time==1` and take the average of each set of ***similarly named columns*** whose names end in `...1C` or `...2C`  (ex: `ex1C`,`ex2C`) at `time==2` to achieve my `Desired_output` below?

*Note: In my actual `Data`, I have several columns ending in `...1S` and `...1C` to average across, so, a functional answer is much appreciated.*

My current inefficient solution is:

```
library(tidyverse)
Data %>%
mutate(ave_ex = case_when(
  time == 1 ~ mean(c(ex1S, ex2S)),
  time == 2 ~ mean(c(ex1C, ex2C))
), 
ave_id = case_when(
  time == 1 ~ mean(c(id1S, id2S)),
  time == 2 ~ mean(c(id1C, id2C))
)) %>% select(-c(ex1S:id2C))
```

```r
Data = read.table(text = "

order DV    score  time  ex1S  ex2S  ex1C  ex2C  id1S  id2S  id1C  id2C     k     t
s-c   ac        1     1     8     5     6     1     2     4     3     7   400    30
s-c   bc        2     1     8     5     6     1     2     4     3     7   400    30
s-c   ac        3     2     8     5     6     1     2     4     3     7   600    50
s-c   bc        4     2     8     5     6     1     2     4     3     7   600    50

", header = TRUE)
```

```r
Desired_output = "

order time DV score   k   t  ave_ex        ave_id
s-c   1    ac 1      400  30 (8+5)/2 =6.5  (2+4)/2 =3
s-c   1    bc 2      400  30 (8+5)/2 =6.5  (2+4)/2 =3
s-c   2    ac 3      600  50 (6+1)/2 =3.5  (3+7)/2 =5
s-c   2    bc 4      600  50 (6+1)/2 =3.5  (3+7)/2 =5

"
```

where `ave_` = average i.e., `mean()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need to automate, we may need a matching with the `time` and the `C`, `S` category.  Below, we select only the 'ex', 'id' columns, then `split`, the data into a `list` of datasets having matching substring of column names i.e. without the digits (`str_remove`), loop over the `list` with `map`, get the `mean`, `enframe` to a two column tibble, create `time` column based on the substring in name, reshape to wide with `pivot_wider` and use the `time` column to join with original Data and select the columns of interest

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
 Data %>% 
  dplyr::select(starts_with("ex"), starts_with("id")) %>% 
  split.default(str_remove(names(.), "\\d+")) %>% 
  map(~ mean(rowMeans(.x))) %>% 
     enframe %>% 
     unnest(value) %>%
     mutate(time = c(1, 2)[str_detect(name, "C") + 1], 
     name = str_c("ave_", str_remove(name, "[A-Z]+"))) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
   left_join(Data, .) %>% 
   dplyr::select(-starts_with("ex"), -starts_with("id"))
```

-output

```
   order DV score time   k  t ave_ex ave_id
1   s-c ac     1    1 400 30    6.5      3
2   s-c bc     2    1 400 30    6.5      3
3   s-c ac     3    2 600 50    3.5      5
4   s-c bc     4    2 600 50    3.5      5
```

Comment: Oh what a glorious synphony.

Comment: Thanks! Imagine column `order` is our `id` variable and our data has several unique orders. In that case, how can we do your code but add `group_by(order)`?

Comment: @SimonHarmel Can you post as a new question.  It is not clear based on your description